# Imagens não alinham na table

Tags: html, table

Tenho esse codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Figuras em tabelas</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1 align="center">Montando figuras com tabelas - 1</h1>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3"><img src="img/verde.gif"></td>
            <td colspan="2"><img src="img/amarelo.gif"></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><img src="img/azul.gif"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"><img src="img/azul.gif"></td>
            <td><img src="img/vermelho.gif"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="img/vermelho.gif"></td>
            <td><img src="img/cinza.gif"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

que está gerando este layout:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem como remover estes espaços entre as imagens?. Já tentei redimensiona-las mas não adianta.

**As imagens separadas:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

provavelmente seja margem da imagem, tenta um `img{margin:0}`
seu código nao tem `css`, você já testou em outros `browsers`?
tenta fornecer mais informações.
segue exemplo apenas para te elucidar:

```
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>Figuras em tabelas</title>
            </head>
            <body>

                <h1 align="center">Montando figuras com tabelas - 1</h1>
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="3"><img src="verde.gif" style="height: 153px;">  </td>
                        <td colspan="2"><img src="amarelo.gif"    ></td>
                        <td rowspan="2"><img src="azul.gif"  style="height: 102px;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="2"><img src="azul.gif"  style="height: 102px;"></td>
                        <td><img src="vermelho.gif"  style="height: 51px;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="vermelho.gif"  style="height: 51px;"></td>
                        <td><img src="cinza.gif"  style="height: 51px;"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Não adiantou o margin, já tentei em todos os navegadores, mesmo assim elas não alinham, se eu juntar elas num editor de imagens, elas alinham corretamente, mas no código não.

Comment: nao teria o tamanho das imagens interferindo no resize das colunas? por exemplo se a imagem azul da direita for maior q a altura do vermelho e amarelo juntos, ou o segndo azul for maior que os dois vermelhos, provavelmente a tabela se adeque. Tente colocar o código completo com imagens e todo o resto. A imagem verde é bem maior que azul+amarelo ou amarelo+vermelho+vermelho.
Ja pensou em usar `divs` com `float left`?

Comment: Adicionei as imagens separadas no tópico. Tenho que usar apenas `table`, não posso usar `div`;

Comment: isso mesmo, cara! é o tamanho das imagens... Ex: se o amarelo e os vermelhos têm 51px de altura("deitados"), o ideal é que o verde tenha 153px, que seria 3x51. e os demais manter 102px, para equivaler a 2x51. Testa ai.

Comment: Não adianta, só piora. Uma coisa que percebi é que as `td` estao maiores que as `img`, mas se eu definir um `height` para a `td`, o tamanho dela continua maior que a imagem.

Comment: A tabela está "esticando" por causa das imagens maiores. copia o código q postei ai e voce vai entender. o height eu usei na imagem, mas o ideal é que voce as redimensione.

Comment: Deu certo, corrigi o tamanho das imagens e ficou tudo ok, Obrigado!